# Java: Not sure how to modify Graphics object within a separate class

Tags: java, user-interface

So my goal for this program is to make a basic Etch-A-Sketch using a GUI. Aside from being able to draw with the mouse, I also need to add a button that changes the line color between any four colors. As I'm just learning this for the first time, I got as far as changing the line color before I ran into an issue:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Etch_A_Sketch implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    JFrame window;
    Container content;
    int mouseX,mouseY,oldX,oldY;
    JButton colorButton;
    ActionListener bPress = new MyListener();

    public Etch_A_Sketch()
    {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Classic Etch a Sketch");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        content = window.getContentPane();
        window.setSize(640,480);
        content.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

        content.addMouseListener(this);
        content.addMouseMotionListener(this);           
        colorButton = new JButton("Click to switch color!");
        colorButton.setSize(175,50);
        colorButton.setVisible(true);
        colorButton.addActionListener(bPress);
        content.add(colorButton);

        window.setVisible(true);
    }


    public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();

    }

    public void mousePressed( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();
        //repaint();
    }

    public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();
        //repaint();
    }

    public void mouseExited( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();
        //repaint();
    }

    public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();
        //repaint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();

        if (oldX ==0 )
        {
            oldX=mouseX;
            oldY=mouseY;
            return;
        }


        Graphics g = content.getGraphics(); // use g to draw onto the pane
        g.drawLine( oldX,oldY, mouseX, mouseY );
        oldX = mouseX;
        oldY = mouseY;
        // repaint();
    }

    public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();
        //repaint();
    }

    class MyListener implements ActionListener
    {
        final Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.ORANGE};
        int index = 0;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {   
            g.setColor(colors[index]);
            index = (index + 1) % colors.length;
        }
    }


    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        new Etch_A_Sketch();
    }
}
```

My problem is this -- I realize the the reference to "g" in the MyListener class is out of scope, because it's part of the mouseDragged method. How would I go about being able to change it when my JButton is pressed? I already tried moving the declaration of g outside the method, but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Also, it might be worth noting that I had a base file to start this project with, and the "//repaint();" lines were already apart of it. I don't know exactly what they mean, though... does it have something to do with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

try placing static global variable at the top of the file;

```
static Graphics g = null;
```

then in the `public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent me)`

```
Etch_A_Sketch.g = content.getGraphics(); // use g to draw onto the pane
```

then reference it in the `class MyListener`

Interestingly  though to be safe, i would recommend using interface. Declare one in the main class, let the class implement it , then fire events whenever you want the value of `content.getGraphics();`

Comment: Introducing static variables, especially ones containing *graphics contexts* might be a really bad idea. For example, what do you reckon will happen if you do this: `new Etch_A_Sketch(); new Etch_A_Sketch();` ? The drawings on the first etch-a-sketch are drawn on the second window!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is pass a reference to the graphics object via a constructor:

```
class MyListener implements ActionListener
{
    private final Graphics graphics;
    private final Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.ORANGE};
    private int index = 0;

    public MyListener(Graphics graphics)
    {
        this.graphics = graphics;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        this.graphics.setColor(colors[index]);
        index = (index + 1) % colors.length;
    }
}
```

Now when creating the ActionListener, instead of doing so...

```
ActionListener bPress = new MyListener();

public Etch_A_Sketch()
{
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Classic Etch a Sketch");
    // ...
    // ...
    colorButton.addActionListener(bPress);
    content.add(colorButton);

    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

you could do this:

```
public Etch_A_Sketch()
{
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Classic Etch a Sketch");
    // ...
    // ...
    Graphics graphics = content.getGraphics();
    colorButton.addActionListener(new MyListener(graphics));
    content.add(colorButton);

    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good OOP design is about separating between what stays the same and what you anticipate you will expand.  You're etcha sketch's pencil is going to expand lot (will add different colors, different thicknesses, producing boxes rather than a scribble, maybe an eraser).  You should create a Pencil class.

```
public class Pencil {
    private Graphics backGroundGraphics;
    final Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.ORANGE};
    private int colorIndex;


public Pencil(BufferedImage backGround) {
    backGroundGraphics = backGround.getGraphics();
    backGroundGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

    public void changeColor() {
        colorIndex++;
        backGroundGraphics.setColor(colors[colorIndex % 4]);
    } 

    public void drawLine(int oldX, int oldY, int mouseX, int mouseY) {
         backGroundGraphics.drawLine(oldX,oldY, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}
```

And then in your GUI class add all this:

```
class  Etch_A_Sketch implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    ...
   private Pencil pencil;
   BufferedImage bf;

   ...
   ...

        public Etch_A_Sketch()
        {
        bf = new BufferedImage(640, 480, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        pencil = new Pencil(bf);
            ....
            ....
}
                           ....

public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();

        if (oldX ==0 )
        {
            oldX=mouseX;
            oldY=mouseY;
            return;
        }

        pencil.drawLine(oldX, oldY, mouseX, mouseY);
        Graphics g2 = content.getGraphics();

        g2.drawImage(bf, 0, 0, content);

        oldX = mouseX;
        oldY = mouseY;

    }


                 ....

class MyListener implements ActionListener
{
    final Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.ORANGE};
    int index = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        pencil.changeColor();
    }
}
```

Now, you are now drawing onto a buffered image.  And then you are drawing that buffered image onto the contentPane.  This eliminates flashing behavior that was arising when I added the new pencil class.  This approach is called "buffering".

Once you get all this, you can even practice a design pattern called Strategy pattern.  This will allow you to change your pencils behavior (rather than draw lines, maybe draw circles or something).  The idea is that the g.drawLine code isn't going to be hard coded in your pencil class.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `getGraphics()` to do painting.

Painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method of a panel with your custom painting code.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of a couple of different approaches for doing custom painting. The examples show you how to draw rectangles of a different color.